# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Diary_Entry'

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Passing in a list of dates 'DiaryEntry' through the foreach loop. every date that it records will be highlighted on the calendar....

```
foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry)
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d);//CALENDAR1 being the ID of the calendar on the aspx page
            }
```

ERROR: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Diary_Entry' because 'Diary_Entry' does not contain a public defination for 'GetEnumerator'

Anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Without knowing more about type `Diary_Entry` it's hard to make good recommendations. Can you show us its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Diary_Entry` meant to be a list of some kind?  Is it based on a collection class, something that implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`?  If not, if it just has a couple of properties that represent dates, you can't use `foreach` with it.  You'd have to process each property separately.

```
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(Diary_Entry.Date1);
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(Diary_Entry.Date2);
// etc.
```

If it has two dates, representing a start and end date, and you want to iterate through the range, you wouldn't be able to use `foreach` with it, but you could still use `for`:

```
for(DateTime d = Diary_Entry.StartDate;d<=Diary_Entry.EndDate;d=d.AddDays(1))
{
   Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DiaryEntry object needs to implement [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> interface.

I suspect you mean to have an array or some other collection of those objects. In that case you could iterate over the collection with a foreach. Another possibility is that DiaryEntry has a collection property on it, and you mean to iterate over that... like the following maybe?

```
foreach(DateTime date in DiaryEntry.Dates) 
{
    ...
}
```